# Java collection to store multiple types of data in key value pairs

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

I am currently working on creating a small framework using the executor and completion services to concurrently execute multiple tasks at the same time. I have another thread that runs independently which monitors the completion service and polls futures every 2 seconds to check for results. When a task fails, I would like to re execute it by submitting it back. I would like to retry up to 3 times. I now need a collection that can let me store the task ID, reference of the task object and the number of retries attempted which would be an integer while keeping the task ID as the unique key. Currently I am using 2 hash maps. One for storing the ID and reference and the other for storing the ID and retry count.

**Edit** My question is that I need suggestions for a collection that would let me store the 3 things by keeping task ID as the unique key to retrieve the task reference and the retry count more efficiently than 2 hash maps.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Added the question. Sorry for not being clear earlier.

Comment: I would suggest to wrapped you task details (like task ref and retry count) in a Class (like TaskDetail) and store task id as key and corresponding object of your wrapper class (Task details) as value.

Comment: But wouldn't that increase the number of objects that need to be created as the number of tasks increase?

Comment: Yes, that will increase the number of the object. So, there will be some question like 1. How may task your application going to have at a certain point of time? Is your memory can tolerate that amount of memory?  When a task successfully executes remove it from the map. You can also use WeakHashMap (solely depends upon your acutal use case).

Comment: Consider `Map<String, Pair<Task,Integer>>`  where task represents  the task object (JavaFX (which comes bundled with Java 8) has the Pair< A,B > class)

Comment: Will try both approaches and get back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a class to hold the tasks and number of execution attemps:

```
public class ExecutionAttempt {
    private final Task task;
    private int numberOfFailedAttempts = 0;

    public ExecutionAttempt(Task task) { ... }

    public int getNumberOfFailedAttempts() { ... }

    public void countFailedAttempt() {
        numberOfFailedAttempts++;
    }

    ...
}
```

Then save the tasks you are currently trying to execute in an ordinary `HashMap`:

```
HashMap<TaskId, ExecutionAttempt> currentlyRunningTaks = ...
```

You could also get away with `Pair<Task, Integer>`, but this could quickly get out of hand as soon as you want to add some additional informations, like `Long averageTimeToFailure` or something like that.

I definitely wouldn't worry about the few tiny `ExecutionAttempt` objects: managing a thread pool and worrying about a dozen additional `ExecutionAttempt` objects is like moving a freight train and worrying about not being able to lift a few additional paper envelopes.